# Embedding a GIF in email

Tags: email

Is it possibly to embed a GIF from giphy.com in my automated email in CiviCRM?

In gmail, I can use Insert Photo / Web Address (URL) and paste in the image (gif) url.

I appreciate your time on responding to this

David

Answer (score 1):

Just insert as img and fill in the giphy url like https://media2.giphy.com/media/dbVNzOSyUd1kQmOIaM/giphy.webp